# How to add label and button controls in .Net ToolTip

Tags: .net, winforms, tooltip

HI,

I want to customize the existing win-form tool-tip control to host child controls like label and buttons with adjustable tool-tip window size and other common tool-tip properties.

Please also suggest any open-source custom tool-tip control which will provide the same kind of functionality.

Thanks

UPDATED: Please check following link, which contains exactly the same thing.

http://www.aicore.co.cc/WinUI/Classes/ToolTip

Comment: I am looking something like following. http://www.aicore.co.cc/WinUI/Classes/ToolTip

Comment: AiCore is not free nor open source. I was not able to download a functional DLL from their website for inclusion in my project. I contacted the developer and he said the same thing, its not free but a freeware version for non-commercial applications may be coming soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with the stock tooltip control in WinForms.

I'm not aware of any Open Source ones that support this, but you could write your own using a special borderless window.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. I think there is some Windows Sub-classing implementation to add child window to tool-tip window.I have few sample code for that, but i am more interested to do that in .net itself.

Comment: http://www.aicore.co.cc/WinUI/Classes/ToolTip  .Please check the link to get the idea what i am talking about. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, i am not sure whether provided link Tool-tip control is the customize version of .Net stock Tool-tip or a custom tool-tip control.

Comment: @AmitSri - i am 99% sure its completely custom.

Answer (score 2):

No this is not possible to add any control to `Tooltip` as it is not a container.

You have to make a user Control, that have label or buttons in it and handle mouse events to show it like tooltip.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. I think there is a way to do that using windows sub-classing. I found an article which will gives us the handle of .net win-forms tool-tip window, using that we can make any user control as child window of tool-tip.It seems to be little bit tricky.So, before i start trying that i want to see any existing code.

Comment: @AmitSri - Could you please share me the article of showing custom tooltip?

Answer (score 0):

[aicore.co.cc/WinUI/Classes/ToolTip](http://aicore.co.cc/WinUI/Classes/ToolTip)
It is not a ToolTip of Windows OS. 
It is a part of my GUI library, developed from scratch.

Comment: Thanks to let me know, Sorry i thought it is possible with the windows Tool-tip.

Comment: Again, AICore is not free and can't be included into your project.