# C# Bubble tooltip with controls inside?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm looking for a way to display several controls inside a bubble tooltip or a similar looking control with other controls inside. The simplest example of this would be a bubble control with a TextBox control inside.

It would be great if control could be positioned based on an X and Y value of another control like a picture box or panel but I do not know how to accomplish this in the C# .NET framework.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: No this is for a C# .NET desktop application

Comment: You can override the content-template of the balloontip.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [How to add label and button controls in .Net ToolTip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5805091/337294). you can take a look at: [AICore](http://www.aicore.co.cc/WinUI/Classes/ToolTip) controls too (Commercial).

Comment: AICore looks great, but it is not free and there are no download links on that site.

Comment: You're right. I should've mentioned it in my answer (not commercial). Updating my answer...

Comment: Thanks I added the DLL but I am not sure why I cannot include its namespace. using AICore.WinUI;
using AICore.WinUI.ElementsControlInternal;
using AICore.WinUI.Design;
using AICore.Collections;
using AICore.Win32;

Comment: Haven't worked with it. But maybe `using AICore.WinUI.ElementsControlInternal;` in meant to be used internally

Comment: Hmm I tried just adding using AICore.WinUI; and it still complains that AICore could not be found. This is after adding the DLL to the project references.

Comment: No, I contacted the developer and the DLL cannot be included within projects.